# Get all compiled Razor views in application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

I'm developing a library for use in ASP.NET Core MVC. For this library, I need to get a list of all (compiled) Razor views (path and content) that exist in the application.

Is there a way to lookup all compiled Razor views in the application during runtime? So far I have not had any luck trying to find out.

Iterating through .cshtml files is no option because they will not be published when using compiled views.

Comment: I think you could not get the content directly. For view content, it will use view data to create this view content. You may could not create the view without viewdata.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For getting complied views path, you could try `ViewsFeature` like

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IViewCompilerProvider _viewCompilerProvider;
    private readonly ApplicationPartManager _applicationPartManager;

    public HomeController(IViewCompilerProvider viewCompilerProvider
        , ApplicationPartManager applicationPartManager)
    {
        _viewCompilerProvider = viewCompilerProvider;
        _applicationPartManager = applicationPartManager;
    }
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var feature = new ViewsFeature();
        _applicationPartManager.PopulateFeature(feature);
        var views = feature.ViewDescriptors;          
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this was what I needed. I guess the original body content is not available anymore for compiled views.

Comment: @Carvellis, the original body content is not included by default. But, as of at least ASP.NET 2.1 it seems that the original content of .cshtml files can be included as a resource in the compiled views assembly by setting the property `EmbedRazorGenerateSources` to `true`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/sdk?view=aspnetcore-2.1#properties-2